# Issue with file input on Safari on iPhone: Not working "every time"

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, safari

I'm encountering a specific issue with a file input in my web application. The input seems to be properly configured to accept files of various types and works as expected on Safari on Mac. However, when I attempt to use the same input on Safari on iPhone, it doesn't work correctly.

In fact it's working maybe 50% of the time.

I've included the code for the input below:

```html
<input multiple="" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/webp, image/bitmap, image/tiff, image/heic, video/mp4, video/avi, video/mov, video/wmv, video/webm, video/flv, video/mpeg, video/mkv, video/ogg" type="file">
```

I've checked various aspects such as compatibility, maximum file size, and the accept attribute, but I can't seem to resolve this specific issue.
Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem or any insights into what might be causing this unexpected behavior?

Thanks !